# How do I get this function to run after all this other code is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, return

I'm creating a register form with jQuery, and I'm trying to add a function to be run upon completion with no errors. What I'm trying to figure out is how to get it run after all the rest is done, so I know what my variable 'hasErrors' is, rather than undefined. Here is my relevant code:

```
$('form.register .submit').click(validateRegister);

function validateRegister(){
    var hasError = false;

    //This is executed if something goes wrong. Basically I want my success() function to be run if this is never run, so at the end.
    function returnErrors() {
            $processing.hide();
            $this.parent().removeClass('processing');
            $endNote.slideUp();
            hasError = true;
    }

    if (hasErrors == false) {
        success();
    }   
        return false;
    }
```

Any help with this is extremely appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Where is `returnErrors` called? You probably have to call `success` inside of it.

Comment: Well returnErrors is called when something goes wrong. Success should execute if returnErrors is never called.

Comment: EDIT**

What I ended up doing was adding 'async: false' to my ajax function, forcing the function to finish before reading the rest. This way, hasError would wait to be defined, and success executed successfully! (hah). Thanks to everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like:

```
function validate() {
  var isValid = false;

  // do some validation here
  // if it passes, set isValid = true

  if (isValid) {
    success();
    return true;
  } else {
    error();
    return false;
  }
}
```

jQuery also has an add-on for form validation that you might be interested in, but it could be overkill depending on how complex your needs are.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, I think you missed the point ;). What I'm trying to figure out is how do I get my isValid variable to be checked after the rest of the code of complete, so success executes then, too.